# fabric ssh connection failed exception capture

Tags: python, fabric

What is the best way to capture failed login (host down) errors from Fabric tasks ??

example:
Warning: Timed out trying to connect to HOSTA (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    timed out

Thanks

Comment: That *specific* exception is very hard to catch and why would you want to? Whats your use case?

Comment: Using Fabric to perform upgrades, on remote linux hosts, that may or may not be online ... they idea was to catch the failed ones, to a log file, and run sum logic to just keep trying to upgrade those from the failed log entries until all are successfully completed. Thanks for your answer in advance.